# Objective-C: Localization in an Efficient Way

Tags: objective-c, localization, nsobject, nslocalizedstring, awakefromnib

I've been localizing my programs by creating strings file and/or localized xib files for every language. This process is very slow since it's complex to maintain all the localized xib files and add new features to the interface.

To avoid this, in my latest projects, I simply made IBOutlets for every UI element on the interface and at `-(void)awakeFromNib` changed the titles and string values for all the elements using `NSLocalizedString` and a strings file.

Is there any other more efficient way to bulk translate all the UI without the need of creating multiple xibs and/or wasting time trying to "keep them in sync"?

I had one idea to solve this, I made a Category of NSObject like the following:

```
@implementation NSObject (Localizable)

-(void)awakeFromNib {

    if ([self isKindOfClass:[NSTextField class]]) {
        NSTextField *txtField = (NSTextField *)self;
        txtField.stringValue = NSLocalizedString(txtField.stringValue, nil);
    }

    else if ([self isKindOfClass:[NSWindow class]]) {
        NSWindow *windowC = (NSWindow *)self;
        windowC.title = NSLocalizedString(windowC.title, nil);
    }

}

@end
```

As you can see on my category I can easily change the values for all the `NSTextField` objects on my application by keeping the translation placeholder as the `NSTextField` text...

This works fine, however I'm concerned about performance since this will run for all objects in my application.

Is it to bad to do this? Are there any better alternatives?

PS: I made a category of `NSObject` and not `NSTextField` or `NSWindow` because this way I can keep all the localization logic in one place and simply add another `else if` statement for every UI class I might want to translate instead of creating a new Category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ibtool` to manage your xib files. It's part of the command-line tools package one installs along with Xcode. While Xcode offers a GUI for editing the strings, `ibtool` can be run from scripts.

Overall, Apple has some guidelines and advice for maintaining xib files; you can find their documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LocalizingInterfaces.html). Reading it, you'll find that `ibtool` is fairly easy to use.

As impressive as the approach you've taken is (I've seen some truly awful ones in which *every* UI element had been connected to an IBOutlet just to effect localization!), it still winds up being additional glue code that has to be maintained (and believe me, you *will* wind up maintaining it as your needs change).

So as far as my two currency units go, I'd recommend sticking to localized nibs.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but another problem I have is that usually I've people from different countries working on the translations and in my approach I can simply send a strings file and ask them to translate. Using multiple xibs means I need to take screenshots, ship them and them populate the UI by myself manually. Is ibtool feature of dumping and importing again reliable?